# Writing specific bits to a binary header

Tags: c

Suppose I want to create binary of a specific length, using the first 4 bits to define the type (Which should allow for 16 different types) and the last 60 bits to define content.

How would one go ahead and construct this in C? I'm having a hard time finding any examples (That properly explains it) of doing this in C (I haven't worked with C this low-level before and I'm trying to get my feet wet...)

Would I just create a `char[8]` and manually set each bit with something like

```
/** Set bit in any sized bit block.
 *
 * @return   none
 *
 * @param   bit    - Bit number.
 * @param   bitmap - Pointer to bitmap.
 *
 * @note    Please note that this function does not know the size of the
 *          bitmap and it cannot range check the specified bit number.
 */
void SetBit(int bit, unsigned char *bitmap)
{
    int n, x;

    x = bit / 8;                        // Index to byte.
    n = bit % 8;                        // Specific bit in byte.

    bitmap[x] |= (1 << n);      // Set bit.
}
```

Above code is from [storing a bit in a bit of character array in C linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537053/storing-a-bit-in-a-bit-of-character-array-in-c-linux)

Comment: `char name[16];` has 16 bytes * 8 bits/byte = 128 bits. `char name[8];` should be enough.

Comment: An array of 16 chars will be 16 x 8 = 128bits

Comment: Math failed me! I'll edit the post above to fix it!

Comment: What is the type? And what is the range of numbers you want to store?

Comment: The 4 bit type would be anything that can be represented by a 4 bit space... Guess that's anything from 0-15

Comment: Better to say `unsigned char` to make clear that there is no sign bit. Plain `char` could be either signed or unsigned

Comment: `bitmap[x] |= (1 << n);` is pretty much the canonical way to work with bitmaps indeed. Never use `1` for the data to shift though, use `1u`.

Comment: @stackptr Even better to use the `uint8_t` type defined in `stdint.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function specific to the task and just use a mask.

```
void setType(uint8_t type, uint8_t* header)
{
    header[0] = (header[0] & 0x0f) | (type << 4);
}

// To use:

uint8_t header[8]; 
setType(3, header);
```

I would create a similar function to set each field of the header.

The above assumes that by "first four bits" you mean the most significant bits of the first byte of the header rather than the least significant bits of the first byte of the header.

Comment: This seems to work for me! Reading the type back would be as simple as `(header[0] & 0xf0) >> 4);` right?

Comment: @MadsRC yes it would. But I would again write a function to encapsulate that.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like this function that will help you set a specific nibble (Nibble is 4bits of data.1 byte(8bit) is 2 Nibbles , probably that was what confused you).This means that you just need to pass your char[x] byte specifying either you need to change left or right hand side part of the byte:

```
int set_nibble(unsigned char* dest,unsigned char src,nibble_side side)
{
    if (side == left_hand )
    {
        *dest = ((*dest & 0x0f) | (src<<4));
        return 0;
    }
    if (side == right_hand )
    {

        *dest = ((*dest & 0xf0) | (src));
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

where nibble_side param is something like

```
typedef enum nibble_side_t
    {
        right_hand, left_hand
    } nibble_side;
```

[Here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/) two decent guides for Binary AND operations.You must feel comfortable to use it for filtering the data you need , before you do operations like this.

Comment: If you go through the trouble of creating enumeration, you should use it's constants in comparison: `if (side == 1)` -> `if (side == left_hand)`.

Comment: Yes thank you.I don't even remember how old this code is.Just recalled it from my repo.I want to give him an example on how you use & as a filter.